# WooCommerce - How to remove sidebar

Tags: woocommerce, sidebar

I need to remove sidebar into my woocommerce store.
I have tried with backend in option theme and in each category but resultless.

I tried also:

1.file wp-template-hooks.php
removed--> do_action(..

2.file archive-product.php 
removed--> do_action(..

3. insert in file function.php in theme dir and  function.php in woocommerce dir 
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
4. into database there is 2 tables with 2 fields serialised but is a risk change this.

resulless.

I finished the ideas.
Where is saved into db the visibility of sidebar? or the variable?

Can you help me?

Thanks
Ale

Answer (score 13):

I just wanted to update this post for WooCommerce version 3.2.3 - 2017

OK the WooCommerce Plugin includes a folder with all the template files if you want to make changes to the template on a custom theme or child theme you need to copy all of the desired template into a folder called woocommerce in your root theme folder. This will overwrite the plugin templates and will allow for WooCommerce updates with overwriting your custom changes. These templates have all of the do_actions and hooks in the comments so it makes it easy to understand how it's working.

That said WooCommerce has hooks that allow for you to add or remove blocks of code you can check out the [API Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) here.

To remove the side bar you need to add this into your functions.php file in your theme setup function

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
```

Update:
You can also remove the side bar on the pages my account and cart by changing the page template from the page editor.

[image]

[image]

Pick a template that does not have the sidebar or create a new template for the theme and remove the line with `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't work - neither on myaccount page nor on cart!

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: It sounds like it is your theme template file. You can change the template for both my account and the cart page by editing the page and from the page attributes sidebar, changing the template to full-width or anything that does not include the sidebar, or creating a new template file and removing  <?php get_sidebar(); ?> from the template.

Answer (score 9):

Please, add this code to your functions.php

```
function mb_remove_sidebar() {
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'mb_remove_sidebar', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed took out the sidebar on all woocommerce pages. /** End #4 */

Answer (score 4):

Add to functions.php the following line:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
} );
```

Comment: I confirm it works in  WooCommerce 6.3.1

Comment: Yeap, this works on WP 6.3.1 and WooCommerce Version 8.0.3

Answer (score 1):

You have already integrated WooCommerce in your theme?

If not, try to do this three steps for [integration WooCommerce in your theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/).

After that, remove *get_sidebar();* from *your_theme/woocommerce.php*

It works fine for me. Screenshot [here](http://prnt.sc/a8qe0i).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, Woocommerce is integrated in theme. In Woocommerce.php into theme i tryed to remove get_sidebar() But resulless

Comment: Doesnt work for me by any option.
I tried to remove action and remove from woocommerce.php file within my theme. doesnt working...

Answer (score 1):

Further to @maksim-borodov's answer, I wanted to hide the sidebar *conditionally*, i.e. only on Product pages. Here's how:

```php
function remove_wc_sidebar_conditional( $array ) {

  // Hide sidebar on product pages by returning false
  if ( is_product() )
    return false;

  // Otherwise, return the original array parameter to keep the sidebar
  return $array;
}

add_filter( 'is_active_sidebar', 'remove_wc_sidebar_conditional', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to functions.php the following line:

remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);

Answer (score 1):

One special case: DIVI theme has sidebar settings, including for WooCommerce, in Theme Options > General

Comment: More specifically, `Theme Options -> Builder -> Product Layout` thanks Divi!

Answer (score 0):

I am using GeneratePress (free version), so the other solutions didn't work for me.

This page gave me the answer: https://docs.generatepress.com/article/sidebar-layout/#sidebar-filter

```
add_filter( 'generate_sidebar_layout', function( $layout ) {
    // If we are on a woocommerce page, set the sidebar
    if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && is_woocommerce() ) {
        return 'no-sidebar';
    }
    // Or else, set the regular layout
    return $layout;
 } );
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be done by woocommerce sidebar plugin. If you want to remove by code add this code to functions.php,

```
  if (!class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {return;}

  if(is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_product() || is_shop() || is_account_page()){ 
  ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    #secondary {
        display: none;
    }
    #primary {
       width:100%;
    }
   </style>
  <?php
 }
}
```

Comment: This only hides, does not remove. Not a clean solution.

Answer (score -4):

Here is **how to remove the sidebar** :-

go to **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce**

in file **single-product.php** remove the following code -

```
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
    ?>
```

next edit the file **archive-product.php** and remove the following code -

```
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
    ?>
```

> (tip* before deleting this, copy and paste the entire code from this page into a seperate text file on your HD...that way you can always paste the original code back into this folder if anything goes wrong)

Comment: I don't think you should be altering plugin files to this! Try removing the action instead, from your theme.

Comment: At the very least you need to copy the original files into you child theme and amend them there. However this still won't be as efficient as you may have to redo alignments if woocommerce updates the code of the original pages.